# Inserting code to HTML view from a pop up initiated from visual view

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to insert html into the HTML view.What i have done is to have tinymce advanced(a wordpress plugin) button that throws a popup and in it is all the necessary things to insert the html.The tinymce buttons are however only visible on the visual view.

Question 1:

Is it a plugin or hack that can allow one to parse html inside the visual view

Question 2:

Is it possible to insert html code to the html view from a popup initiated from the visual view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to **dashboard -> settings -> tinymce advanced**

then add the "view HTML" button to your toolbar... that should do it.